# How can I access elements inside a list within a dictionary python?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have a function that's returning a json formatted dataset. Here's a sample:

```
[{u'category': [u'Transfer', u'Withdrawal', u'ATM'], u'category_id': u'21012002', u'_account': u'XARE85EJqKsjxLp6XR8ocg8VakrkXpTXmRdOo', u'name': u'ATM Withdrawal', u'amount': 200, u'meta': {u'location': {u'city': u'San Francisco', u'state': u'CA'}}, u'date': u'2014-07-21', u'score': {u'location': {u'city': 1, u'state': 1}, u'name': 1}, u'_id': u'0AZ0De04KqsreDgVwM1RSRYjyd8yXxSDQ8Zxn', u'type': {u'primary': u'special'}, u'pending': False}] 

for trans in foodie_data:
            print 'Name={},Amount={},Date={}, Categories ={}\n'.format(trans['name'],trans['amount'],trans['date'],trans['category'])
```

This script prints:

```
Name=ATM Withdrawal,Amount=200,Date=2014-07-21,Categories=[u'Transfer', u'Withdrawal', u'ATM']
```

I want it to return Categories as a string and not a list:

```
Name=ATM Withdrawal,Amount=200,Date=2014-07-21,Categories='Transfer, Withdrawal,ATM']
```

What's the most efficient way of doing so?

Comment: `', '.join(trans['category'])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two quick fix in your code should solve it

1. Join the list returned by `trans['category']` separated by comma such that it is a string rather than a string representation of list.
2. Quote the format specifier for `category` i.e. `Categories =\'{}\'`

   ```
   for trans in foodie_data:
       print 'Name={},Amount={},Date={}, Categories =\'{}\'\n'.format(
       trans['name'],
       trans['amount'],
       trans['date'],
       ', '.join(trans['category']))
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You can join the elements of categories:

```
>>> categories = [u'Transfer', u'Withdrawal', u'ATM']
>>> ",".join(categories)
u'Transfer,Withdrawal,ATM'
```

and use it instead when printing your output:

```
",".join(trans['category'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also you the dict directly with `str.format` to access the rest of the values:

```
for trans in foodie_data:
    print "Name={name},Amount={amount},Date={date}," \
       "Categories='{}'\n".format(",".join(trans["category"]),**trans)


 Name=ATM Withdrawal,Amount=200,Date=2014-07-21,Categories='Transfer,Withdrawal,ATM'
```